# How to avoid code duplication if multiple pages look almost the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a couple of pages for e.g. `Product` that look almost the same. I have `Product/Add` and `Product/Modify/{id}` pages where one is an empty form to add new `Product` and the second one comes already filled with data for a current product and can be updated with additional information. Because Razor Pages separates this into `Add` and `Modify` PageModels, I have a different `cshtml` view for each of them.

I tried to use ViewComponents to build reusable parts of these views, but they are only good if all you want to do is *display* data. Because ViewComponents don't support Binding all I have left is somehow send ajax requests and append the data to submit, which even sounds wrong and probably isn't the right approach.

Is there any other way of creating these pages without duplication?

Comment: Partials are only good for displaying data. ViewComponents are much more powerful^_^

Comment: @AdamVincent ViewComponents allow to inject dependencies to retrieve data, but there is no way to modify this data and send back from ViewComponent. E.g. create a ViewComponent with a list of items that a user can select and then send back on post information about which items user selected.

Comment: In my opinion, code duplication is much less of a concern at the layer of abstraction in question (UI). It's more important that your business logic is re-usable, but if you tie your /Product/Modify to say a /User/Modify with a piece of view logic, when you go to update your products which may change rapidly, you risk breaking /User/

Comment: You're right, with ViewComponents you pass in a copy of the viewData that the calling code has.  If you want to do ajax calls to a api controller in razorpages, you could scaffold a new page, and just return JSON (instead of the Page) like a classic api controller, or you could use api controllers side by side with razorpages.

Comment: @AdamVincent What if my view contains a custom made dual list. I expect this list  to work the same on every page. It basically allows me to select a couple of items from one list and move them to another. But I need to send information about which items were selected on post. With ViewComponents I cannot do that, because they don't allow binding.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm going to try it and get back to you.

Comment: Are [Editor Templates](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/) still a thing in asp.net-core? The dual list could be a candidate for its own editor.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Yes!! This is exactly it! Beautiful, thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. It is a shame that there is absolutely no documentation for Editor Templates in Razor Pages. All of the examples are for MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one page for create and edit by sending a new object of the Product model (with no data in id attribute) and a created object (with data in id attribute) in case of editing. And in the view you can do rendering based on the sent object (whether it is new or not).